# Provisioning Profile Invalid

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile

profile for all my apps but it became invalid, I know I can just edit it and the problem will go away but I've just updated it 2hours ago and after that it became invalid again and I don't know what cause the problem

btw here are some screenshots.

[image]
[image]

and last I'm just wondering why I have multiple Certificate for Distribution and Development, Can I just revoke to 2 and will it affect my projects?

Comment: just revoke and try to create a new one. that will be the easiest way. Don't forget to restart XCode.

Comment: I want to understand on how this works.

Comment: Did you try to fix the code signing issue using Xcode?

Comment: No I didn't It just became invalid but if I edit it, It will become valid again I just want to know why that happens and Why I have multiple cert even If I only created one.